# Visual Studio freezes or hangs while building VSTO / Word Add-In project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsto

I just added a new Word AddIn project to my blank solution and just pressed the build button. Visual Studio freezes for about 2 - 3 minutes every time....

I have a 64bit machine

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you got Visual Studio SP1 installed? Otherwise the addin will be installed and seen visible in your Program and Features. Probably this is taking time to launch your addins everytime.